# Why doesn't except object catch everything in Python?

Tags: python, exception, python-2.x, python-internals

The python language reference states in [section 7.4](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> For an except clause with an expression, that expression is evaluated, and the clause matches the exception if the resulting object is “compatible” with the exception. An object is compatible with an exception if it is the class or a base class of the exception object, or a tuple containing an item compatible with the exception.

So, why doesn't `except object:` catch everything? `object` is the base class of all exception classes, so `except object:` should be able to catch every exception.

For example, this should catch the `AssertionError`

```
print isinstance(AssertionError(), object) # prints True
try:
    raise AssertionError()
except object:
    # This block should execute but it never does.
    print 'Caught exception'
```

Comment: You need to put an exception type there, and `object` isn't an exception type. I'm not sure why this doesn't trigger a `TypeError`, though.

Comment: This only works in 2.x, by the way. In 3.x, it will throw a TypeError. My assumption would be that it fails due some to some missing magic method, but I couldn't tell you which one(s). `AssertionError` has the following attribute that `object` doesn't have `{'__setstate__', 'args', '__context__', '__suppress_context__', '__dict__', '__cause__', 'with_traceback', '__traceback__'}`, so I assume it's because of one of those.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the 2.x exception handling. Python 3 has the correct check to catch non-exception types. Python 2 just silently does the wrong thing.

Comment: The language reference should probably be updated to mention that you need an exception type there. The docs don't seem to have kept up properly with changes to the exception mechanics over the years. It used to be the case that you *could* raise and catch any class, back before type/class unification and then the introduction of `BaseException` and new-style exception classes.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm using python 2 which does allow any object to be raised

Comment: @Evan: No it doesn't. Try `raise 4`, and you'll get a `TypeError` instead of raising `4`.

Comment: @user2357112 true but this works `class A: pass` `raise A` and A is not a descendent of `BaseException`.

Comment: @Evan: That's an old-style class. All old-style classes count as exception classes, because `BaseException` and the requirement to descend from it didn't exist back when they originally introduced class-based exceptions and started moving away from string exceptions.

Comment: documentation bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer can be found in the [source code for python 2.7](https://github.com/tadhgmister/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/ceval.c#L4841):

```
        else if (Py_Py3kWarningFlag  &&
                 !PyTuple_Check(w) &&
                 !Py3kExceptionClass_Check(w))
        {
            int ret_val;
            ret_val = PyErr_WarnEx(
                PyExc_DeprecationWarning,
                CANNOT_CATCH_MSG, 1);
            if (ret_val < 0)
                return NULL;
        }
```

so if `w` (I assume the expression in the `except` statement) is not a tuple or exception class *and the `Py_Py3kWarningFlag` is set* then trying to use an invalid exception type in the except block will show a warning.

That flag is set by adding the `-3` flag when executing your file:

```
Tadhgs-MacBook-Pro:~ Tadhg$ python2 -3 /Users/Tadhg/Documents/codes/test.py
True
/Users/Tadhg/Documents/codes/test.py:5: DeprecationWarning: catching classes that don't inherit from BaseException is not allowed in 3.x
  except object:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Tadhg/Documents/codes/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise AssertionError()
AssertionError
```

Comment: It's not falling through to the `default` case; it goes to `PyErr_GivenExceptionMatches(v, w)`, which ends up using the old code path for now-removed string exceptions.

Comment: Yes I realized that after taking a longer look at the code.  I figured posting a bad/inaccurate answer with links to the definitely relevant code was worth posting so that people like you could correct me :D

Comment: Strangely, Python 2 seems to let you put pretty much anything for an `except` expression, but it silently behaves contradictory to the documentation if you give it a type that isn't an exception type. The documentation should at least be updated, though in Python 2's current maintenance-only state, it's probably not worth doing anything to the behavior.

Comment: Slightly unsatisfying but good to know it is one of those spec does not match the implementation issues.